# AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, csv, data-science

my code:

```
# opening CSV
with open('notables.csv', 'w') as notables:
    file_write=csv.writer(notables, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    # write
    # TO DO: how to get the values to write as well?
    file_write.writerow(data1)
    
    # close file
    file_write.close()
```

my error:

```
 file_write.close()

 AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Am I suppose to close a csv file when done? If so, how?

Comment: `file_write` is a `csv.writer` object, not a file object. `notables` is a file object, but you used a with statement, the whole point of that is so it *closes it for you automatically*,

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you're trying to close something that isn't close-able.  Just remove that line, and because you opened the file in a `with ...` context, you don't need to close *anything*, Python will manage that for you:

```py
# opening CSV
with open('notables.csv', 'w') as notables:
    file_write=csv.writer(notables, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    # write
    # TO DO: how to get the values to write as well?
    file_write.writerow(data1)
```